# How not to ruin negative numbers NaN|0

Tags: javascript, nan

When trying to get false for NaN I am also ruining negative numbers

```
-0.2|0     //this will always return zero If the number is negative
```

What I wanted to do was a bitwize inline as quick as possible asking as little as I can as I am setting the answer into an array at the same time as I am asking.

```
array[i]=(sum)|0
```

my sum sometimes will produce NaN

**Ok, to make my question clearer and get to the root... why is -0.2 false when -1 is not? -0.2 is not zero! zero is false but -0.2 is less than zero -0.2!==0**

Comment: Count number of "as" in your question. :)

Comment: What do you expect to get as the output for `-0.2|0`?

Comment: The bitwise operator `|`  acts like Math.floor except that it never returns a NaN. Where Math.floor would return NaN, bitwise or will return 0

Comment: that is an example of how I will get zero if the number is negitive (I expect zero!) I didn't expect negitives though and am unsure of how to get around this (as)

Comment: Coerce to a number first; `array[i]= +sum | 0`

Comment: I guess you need something like this: `Math.max(sum, 0)`. This allows to ensure the number is not negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first cast sum to a Number (not an integer, which is what does `|`) and if it returns `NaN` you can assign zero instead like this:

```
array[i]= (+sum) || 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why you would want to make it "as short as possible" just for the sake of inlining it in an expression. Good code does not equal short code.

In that spirit, consider something like

```
function nanToZero( number ) {
    return isNaN( number ) ? 0 : number;
}

// usage
array[i] = nanToZero( sum );
```

Comment: LOL, function calls are expensive! I never said 'short', Good code would be efficient by not needing to ask many questions and certainly not calling extra functions per iteration of an array

Comment: @8DK No, efficient code is also not the equivalent of good code. Good code is maintainable, readable and modular. Inlining things like this breaks such clean code patterns. Only optimize performance after you have proven that you *need* it, otherwise, as Donald Knuth said many years ago, you are working on the root of all evil. You haven't mentioned performance restrictions so I assumed you actually haven't proven this. Keep in mind that even jQuery consists of many, many functions, so it really isn't *that* expensive.

Comment: Also, assuming the downvote is yours, I don't see how this justifies the downvote either way, but as I always say: whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @8DK One last thing. Even if you care for performance, this approach is superior. Just use proper post-processing that will take care of inlining. Performance is one of the worst excuses for sloppy coding. With minification that takes care of inlining in an intelligent way you get the best of both worlds: good code and your performance.

Comment: I down voted you because your answer was the opposite of what I asked (as quick as possible and inline). I also down voted you because  you assumed that I wanted short code. +(sum)||0 vs what you put!? I can read that! sloppy?

Comment: @8DK I'm not going to give you an introduction into clean code here. There is plenty of literature on the subject of encapsulation. There is a reason constructs like "function" exist opposed to just writing one big block of code, which, according to you, would have to be so superior. It just isn't, but again: if you want to work like a professional, just read up on the literature.